# Robomongo not switching keyboard layouts without reload on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, database, mongodb

I have installed `Robomongo` 0.8.4(a `mongodb` administering tool) on Ubuntu 13.10 with a deb-package downloaded from it's official site.

When I switch the keyboard layout it does switch system-wide but it doesn't affect `Robomongo` which continues using the same one.

The correct keyboard layout is set in `Robomongo` when you restart it. But of course restarting the program just to switch the keyboard is painful.

Has somebody encountered such a problem on either this program or may be another?

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known (and still open) bug with Robomongo, likely related to similar Qt bugs.  You can track the issue here:

https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/469

For now, as you have noted, a restart is necessary for it to pick up the changes.

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue I myself submitted to the Github. I should have published the link to it earlier.

Comment: Now I feel bad for nabbing the answer, if I could upvote you more than once I would :)